# c style loop for in python

Tags: python, loops

I need c style loop for:

```
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
```

There's equivalent i've found, but when iterating with big number of iterations, it consumes a lot of memory.

```
for i in range( 0, n ):
```

Is there any other equivalent?

Comment: I suggest you post the real problem you have, where you actually need such a loop. There may very well be better alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use xrange instead of range, which uses a generator instead of building a whole list.

Comment: Note : in Python 3 `range` returns a generator and `xrange` exists no longer.

Comment: Also, `xrange` doesn't return a generator in the conventional sense. It is a natively implemented type (try `type (xrange(10))`). More details available at http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange

Answer (score 3):

Use `xrange` instead of `range` to prevent the list from being constructed upfront. That will reduce your memory cost.

Either that or use a `while` loop with a counter and `break` when it reaches `n`.

Usually, I've found that using a `C` style loop while coding in Python is a hidden stylistic problem. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `while` loops with counters are very unpythonic. Use `enumerate` instead where you'd use such a construct in other languages.

Comment: `enumerate` would be used to go through a list along with indices. The `while` situation is different. However, it *is* slower than a `for` with `xrange` so yes, somewhat less pythonic than that.

Answer (score 2):

Use `xrange`

```
for i in xrange(n):
```

which returns an iterator rather than a list. Or upgrade to Python 3, where `range` gets the semantics of `xrange`.

Answer (score 1):

`xrange` will consume less memory than `range`.
The difference is that `range` stores all the range values in a list, while `xrange` just yields value one by one.

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange

Answer (score 1):

If `n` is not known at the start of the loop, you can iterate over [`count`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) from itertools.

```
from itertools import count

for i in count():
    if some_condition(i):
        break
    do_stuff()
```

The `count` iterator takes optional *start* and *step* arguments. I think the above is more pythonic than the usual way of doing it, which is

```
i = 0
while not some_condition(i):
    do_stuff()
    i += 1
```

The `i = 0` setup bothers me with this approach, and as the contents of the `while` block grows more complex with added `break` and `continue` statements, making sure the `i` variable gets incremented becomes a tedious and error-prone task. This rearrangement solves the last problem:

```
i = -1
while True:
    i += 1
    if some_condition(i):
        break
    do_stuff()
```

But it's still messy and inelegant compared to using `count`.

Answer (score 0):

In older Pythons, use `xrange()` instead of `range()`, it doesn't create an actual (in-memory) list.